# Android Facebook SDK 3 posting to friends feed doesnt work

Tags: android, facebook, feed, facebook-android-sdk, friend

Can someone send REALLY working NOW simple?

I'm use next:

1) Make authorization in app

2) then on button pressed publishFeedDialog();

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");

 params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
   params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for And0roid makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
  params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
 params.putString("picture", "");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(activity,
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {

                Log.e("TAG",values.toString());

                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity,
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }



        })
        .setFrom("")
       .setTo(userId)
        .build();
         feedDialog.show();
}
```

While I send messsage I see that my friend currectly recognized from Id.

I receive something like:

```
Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed
Redirect URL: fbconnect://success?post_id=1266196038_167455066740536
```

But message in frends feed doesnt appear.
Code without .setTo(userId) send me at feed my message as normal.

In authorization I use

```
List<String> permission = new ArrayList<String>();

        permission.add("publish_actions");
        permission.add("publish_stream");
```

and write app_id in manifest.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Help me please!

P.S. Does send to friend's feed at facebook working now (after feb 2013) ?

Comment: where is the url for `picture` ?

Comment: u should also avoid `.setFrom("")`

Comment: it doesn't change anything, believe me. I was try without ".setFrom" before (owner message=id only my auth fb account) & with picture but result = nothing. =))

Comment: have change anything in `WebDialog` class of Facebook SDK ? where is the link of picture in your above code ?

Answer (score 0):

(Edit): This is only applicable via the graph API.

[Look here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/02/06/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) at the second last point under February 2013 Breaking Changes Now Live. Its no longer available.

Comment: the link u have given is about Graph-Api. but the problem he has asked about is `FeedDialog`. facebook recommended to post to friends and own wall using `FeedDialog`.

Comment: Apologies I miss read it. The blog post just says about it being removed not recomending to do it using `FeedDialog`.

Comment: chefburns, what you recomending to use?!

Comment: I wasn't I thought it was removed from the wording of the blog post but according to @Shoshi Facebook recomend using the `FeedDialog`

Comment: chefburns, maybe I'd already use it. FeedDialogBuilder make FeedDialog! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/